# Overflow Hidden Image inside border

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, overflow, image-resizing

I have this code

```
<Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5" Grid.Row="0"
                     Tap="ContentControl_Tap" Background="Transparent">
    <Image x:Name="ImgTop" ManipulationDelta="Top_ManipulationDelta" Stretch="Uniform" >
 </Border>
```

I cannot set width of the image (i can have different images, and images can have different size... I cannot crop the image)

I need to "hide" the excess of the image... the problem is that when image is too big the excess go ON the border, not under.... Any idea how can i solve the problem?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was from awhile ago, but I just ran into a similar issue and I think I've got a solution.

I have a Grid that is 340x162 and I'm planning to create an image rotator of some sort inside of it. I'm considering animating the image into a negative top margin to have the image pan out slightly before it goes to the next slide.  However, when the image moves up it goes outside the border.

My solution is to create a clip on the Border, as follows:

```
<Border Width="340" Height="162">
     <Border.Clip>
          <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,340,162" />
     </Border.Clip>
     <Image Name="Image1" Source="Assets/my-image.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0 -20 0 0"/>
</Border>
```

That clips the border starting at the point 0,0 and it uses a rectangle that is 340x162, which is the same size as the border. As soon as I added that, the negative margin on the image didn't pull the image out of the border.

Hope that helps someone...